# git: 'log master..origin/master' not behaving as expected

Tags: git

I'm trying to compare my copy of 'master' to that on the remote repository which it tracks. I thought that the following command would work, and often it seems to.  However, sometimes it produces nothing and yet I know that the remote branch has many changes, which I can confirm by doing a pull.

```
git log master..origin/master
```

Can anyone explain this behavior and tell me what command I should be using to determine the changes between local and remote?

[Another piece of data: I've had it happen that 'git log master..origin/master' produces nothing. Then I do a pull. The pull fails because I have a working copy of some file. After this, 'git log master..origin/master' *does* show me the differences.  It seems the pull has updated some local log? If so, how could I achieve this without doing (or attempting to do) a pull?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `origin/master` is a remote branch in *your repository*. It represents where origin's master branch was the last time you "looked" (fetched, which is part of pull and remote update).

When you pull, the fetch is performed, and `origin/master` gets updated. Then pull calls merge, which may or may not fail, but this has no effect on your remote branches.

You can also use `git fetch --all` or `git fetch origin` to get those updates.

Answer (score 1):

`pull` is a `fetch` and a `merge`. Fetch downloads its logs from a remote server. I think this is what you are observing here.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html

Answer (score 1):

It will only show you some differences if you did fetch something out of origin (to the local references of origin in your local repo).

That is why you see a difference after even a failed `git pull`:

- it first fetch
- then attempt to merge (and fail)

, but that is enough for the `git log` to extract the information you need, because they are on your local repo (after the `fetch` part)